# Infura vs Alchemy vs Cloudflare-ETH?

Tags: web3js, ether, infura

Infura - free/paid

Alchemy - free/paid

Cloudflare-ETH - full free

Can someone explain to me why all video tutorials dApp on youtube use Infura instead of completely free CloudFlare?

Comment: People are free to choose. Sometimes being the first will give you an advantage.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing.